# How to preserve borders while using css filters

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an image tag inside that has a two pixel border. When applying a filter to this image to make it greyscale or "black and white" I see the image as black and white, but then the border colors are not preserved, and also take on this trait. I can also make the outside div take on these borders, but the width of div is set to 100% which makes the outer box have the borders rather than the image itself.

```
<div class="article-inline"><img src="images/bg/beach-girl.jpg" /></div>

.article-inline
{
    width: 100%;
}
.article-inline img
{
    height: 400px;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    filter: url(../desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: gray;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   border-left: solid 2px #ff0000;
   border-top: solid 2px #ff0000;
   border-right: solid 2px #ffd200;
   border-bottom: solid 2px #ffd200;
}
```

Comment: wrap img in div tag and make it display:inline-block and apply borders to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by put `img` into a `div` and apply `inline-block` and border properties just like following example

```css
.article-inline {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.bordercl {
  border-left: solid 2px #ff0000;
  border-top: solid 2px #ff0000;
  border-right: solid 2px #ffd200;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #ffd200;
  display: inline-block;
}

.article-inline img {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  /* overflow:auto; */
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  filter: url(../desaturate.svg#greyscale);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="article-inline">
  <div class="bordercl">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixes the border colors, but now the margin auto gets ignored, and it no longer is in the center of the outer div set to width 100%. It instead aligns left.

Comment: I added text-align: center to the article-inline class and it fixes the center problem :-)